# Prove that the number of positive divisors of a is given by the product $(e_1 + 1)(e_2 + 1)...(e_n + 1)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a$ be a positive integer with factorization $a = p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2}...p_n^{e_n}$. Prove that the number of positive divisors of a is given by the product $(e_1 + 1)(e_2 + 1)...(e_n + 1)$.

I know that from the fundamental theorem of arithmetics, that if $a\geq2$, then $a$ can be factored as a product of prime numbers. However, I'm not sure how I can use this knowledge to answer this question. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If $d$ is a positive divisor of $p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_n^{e_n}$, then $d = p_1^{b_1} p_2^{b_2} \cdots p_n^{b_n}$ with $b_j \in \{0,1,\dots,e_j\}$. How many chooses for $d$ there are?

Comment: Thank you Don Thousand, it does help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A positive divisor is of the form $ p_1^{a_1} p_2^{a_2}...p_n^{a_n}$.

There are $e_i+1$ choices for each $a_i$ and so the number of choices is the product of these, as you have given.

Comment: Could you explain the second part

Comment: Maybe do not accept an answer you do not understand? The 2nd part is due to the fact that for each $p$ you can assign it an exponent ranging from 0 - e, so you get e+1 choices for every p. If that doesn't make sense, remember that if you count from 1-10, you count 10 numbers, so if you count from 0-10, you count 11 numbers. Hope that clears it up @Rosan

Answer (score 1):

If $a=p_{1}^{e_1} \ldots p_{n}^{e_n}$ then $b$ is a divisor of $a$, if, and only if, $b=p_{1}^{f_1} \ldots p_{n}^{f_n}$ where $0\leq f_i\leq e_i$. The is just a combinatorics problem and using the multiplicative principle you get that the number of positive divisors of a is given by the product $(e_1+1)(e_2+1)...(e_n+1)$.

Comment: How would I use the multiplicative principle?

Comment: as $p_i$ are given, there is a one to one relation between the divisors of $a$ and the set of all $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ such that $x_i \in \{0, 1,\ldots, e_i\}$, i.e, the set $ \prod  \{0, 1,\ldots, e_i\}$. The multiplicative principle states that this set has a cardinality of $(e_1+1) \cdots (e_n+1)$.